# Can Olingo v2.x and v4.x run side-by-side?

Tags: odata, olingo

Can Olingo v2.x and v4.x run in the same Java webapp side-by-side?

I know some libraries like Jackson 1.x and 2.x support this: [a project can depend on both Jackson 1.x and 2.x, without conflicts](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using just *Olingo 4*, but as far as I know *v2* and *v4* are growing independently. I don't think it would be a problem to use them both.

And, in the worst scenario, you can use *Olingo 2* for *OData 2* and [*SDL OData Frameworks*](https://github.com/sdl/odata) for *OData 4*, which are totally different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. I've encapsulated olingo-odata2 and olingo-odata4 in their own Spring Framework based REST controllers and provide services side by side.